# How can I get the used configure commandline options for the installed Qt5

Tags: qt5, configure

I want to check if Qt5 was compiled with or without some options, regarding supported image formats. I know about the QImageReader supportedImageFormats function but I want to know the configure options.

Is there a way to retrieve the used commandline options of the configure call dynamically?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is not. You could fake it, if you still have the source tree. In qt5/qtbase you find two files: config.summary and config.status. Those contain the info you seek. However, these files are not part of a normal installation.